# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level error invoking click function in a loop using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, indentation

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_liPrev" class="disabled">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_PreviousPageButton" title="«" class="aspNetDisabled">«</a>
        </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_0" class="active">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_0" class="aspNetDisabled">1 </a>
        </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_1">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_1" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl01$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">2 </a>
        </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_2">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_2" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl02$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">3 </a>
        </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_3">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_3" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl03$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">4 </a>
        </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_pager_li_4">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_4" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$Repeater1$ctl04$PageLink&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">5 </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_NextSectionButton" title="..." href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$NextSectionButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">...</a>
        </li>
        <li id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_liNext">
            <a id="MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_NextPageButton" title="»" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainCopy$ctl19$Pager$NextPageButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">»</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
        pagination = len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_']"))
        print(pagination)# length is 5
        for page in range(1, pagination):
            print(page) # 1 
            browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_" + str(page) +' ]")
```

1. I tried this code to switch to another page.
2. this code is not working
3. How can we switch to all the links one after another with waiting time 3 seconds
4. After reaching last page it should stop automatically

Comment: _...code is not working..._: What happens exactly?

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: i have placed in the right position still i am getting same error

Comment: The code you present doesn't have any unindent. So it is likely the indentation error is reported on the *next* line. It should line up with `browser` or `for` or some previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is a mixup of *`blank`* characters and *`tab`* characters within the lines of code under `for` loop.

```
    for page in range(1, pagination):
        print(page) # 1 
    ^^^ check for space/tab characters here
        browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^='MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_" + str(page) +' ]")
    ^^^ check for space/tab characters here
```

---

### Solution

Use either the *`blank`* characters or the *`tab`* character, but don't mix up both.

Comment: issue is with this ("[id^='MainCopy_ctl19_Pager_Repeater1_PageLink_" + str(page) +' ]")